# I can't get a returned JSON object from form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a bit of jQuery that (I thought) would serialize, parse into JSON, and return JSON from a form. It looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
        $('form').submit(function() {
            var formData =  $(this).serialize();
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(formData);
            $.getJSON(jsonData);
            //alert(jsonData[0].name);
            console.log(jsonData);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And the HTML looks like any normal form. But when I submit it, it just clears the form and doesn't log anything to the console.

Comment: `serialize()` does not return JSON.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is for making AJAX requests, not for parsing JSON data.

Comment: The answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery) might get you started.

Comment: What do you think `serialize` returns, that would need to be "*parsed into JSON*"? I don't think you need [JSON strings](http://json.org/) here at all (and if you did, you had to use `JSON.stringify`).